# IntelliTrace and asp.net temporary files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, intellitrace, system-center

We just got a shiny new System Centre and one of the features we were more exited about was running IntelliTrace on exceptions happening in our production environment.

We have several `WebForms` applications, which are Website projects and these create temporary assemblies in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

When an exception happens and I download the `.iTrace` file and start a debugging session, I get a message along the lines of `Could not find aXsdressf_001dcv.pdb`,(I don't even think the temporary files have PDBs created, do they?) and these are temporary assemblies that exist on the production server, which I don't even have filesystem access to.

So how do I run these IntelliTraces? I hope there is a simple workaround here, which I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to pre-compile your asp binary and re-deploy?

IntelliTrace file debugging is kind of Like dump debugging, PDB will make the life easier by potentially pointing you directly to the source code, but without that you can still get a lot of useful information from the file.

Are you able to see a "Summary Page" when open the .itrace file? Where you should be able to find a list of all the exceptions. When start debugging one of the exception, even without the pdb file you can still make use of the other debugger windows like locals window and call stack window, and you should be able to see the exception and other related events in IntelliTrace window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunatly, for these applications it is not possible to pre-compile. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: pdb will make the life easier by pointing you directly to the source code, but without it there is still a whole bunch of information in the .itrace file, such as the exception type, exception message, the call stack for the exception, and some local variables. This will most like lead you to the right code if it's your own code base.